# Problem in connecting with oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, docker, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created one **connection** in **Oracle** with name **Oracle18c**. Whenever I am trying to open **Tables** section then below pop-up is coming. My **Oracle server** is running in **Docker** container. I tried to find the solution in the internet but I couldn't find it. I am new to the **Oracle** database. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: If you execute `docker ps` from shell does it list your Oracle database process?

Comment: yes it is showing in the list

Comment: From docker terminal login as sysdba `docker exec -it --user=oracle container_name sqlplus / as sysdba` and follow the instructions posted by @pmdba

Comment: @Kumar After running above command I am getting this error. OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"sqlplus\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Answer (score 0):

By default, pluggable databases do not open automatically when their container database starts up. A sysdba user needs to issue the command "alter pluggable database all open" to put them into read-write mode. Your error suggests that that hasn't happened here. Check this link for details on how to do that:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-startup-and-shutdown-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1#:~:text=Pluggable%20Database%20(PDB)%20Automatic%20Startup,-The%2012.1.&text=Prior%20to%2012.1.,or%20all%20of%20the%20PDBs.

Answer (score 0):

My container was built from scratch Oracle 18 xe source:  [github](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles).

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS                                                                          NAMES
13afebdbdbdc        oracle/database:18.4.0-xe   "/bin/sh -c 'exec $O…"   8 hours ago         Up 7 hours (healthy)   



   $ docker exec -it xedb  ps -ef | grep xe
    oracle    1736     1  0 09:42 ?        00:00:01 xe_pmon_XE
    oracle    1738     1  0 09:42 ?        00:00:00 xe_clmn_XE
    ------------------------
    59 lines......
$ docker exec -it --user=oracle xedb sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jun 18 15:45:11 2020
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL> show con_name   -- container name

NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT



 SQL> show pdbs

        CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
    ---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
             2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
             3 XEPDB1                         READ WRITE NO
    SQL>
```

Instance is up and running as well as pluggable database

If you're unable to login as sysdba from docker terminal.You can try with bash command

```
$ docker exec -it --user=oracle xedb  bash
[oracle@13afebdbdbdc /]$
```

If that doesn't work as a Oracle user   exclude `--user` parameter,use bash command

```
$ docker exec -it xedb  bash
bash-4.2# su oracle   -- switch oracle user 
[oracle@13afebdbdbdc /]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME   -- verify environment
/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
[oracle@13afebdbdbdc /]$ echo $ORACLE_SID
 XE
```

If your environment returns nothing you can set environment with the command below

```
    [oracle@13afebdbdbdc /]$ . oraenv   -- dot space oraenv
    ORACLE_SID = [XE] ?
    The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
    [oracle@13afebdbdbdc /]$ rlwrap sqlplus / as sysdba

    SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jun 18 15:58:39 2020
    Version 18.4.0.0.0

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

    Connected to an idle instance

     SQL> startup    -- start the database
    ORACLE instance started.

     Total System Global Area 1610609288 bytes
     Fixed Size                  8897160 bytes
     Variable Size             620756992 bytes
     Database Buffers          973078528 bytes
     Redo Buffers                7876608 bytes
     Database mounted.
     Database opened.
SQL> select open_mode from v$database;  -- check database status 

OPEN_MODE
--------------------
READ WRITE


SQL> show pdbs     -- check pdb open mode is read write

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 XEPDB1                         READ WRITE NO
```

If you happen to see Pluggable database in mount state

```
SQL> show pdbs      -- pdb xepdb1 is in mount state 

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 XEPDB1                         MOUNTED
SQL> alter pluggable database xepdb1 open;   -- open pdb 


Pluggable database altered.

SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 XEPDB1                         READ WRITE NO

SQL> alter pluggable database xepdb1 save state ; --------next restart pdb will be opened automagically 


Pluggable database altered.
```